# Can Mother-to-Child Transmission Occur in Relation to Mycotoxins or Mycoestrogens?

Tags: mycology

There are 17 officially noted cases in which leukemia or melanoma cancer cells crossed the placenta from mother to child. Other crossings include metals (or metalloid elements), such as mercury or arsenic (just as an example). There are also crossings of bacteria, viruses, and general foodborne illnesses.

With all this in mind, my question is: "Can a mother who is hosting a mold, transfer that to her unborn child?"

(Please don't supply an answer about how the child is at risk during the birthing process or caesarean section. Other than that, even opinions are welcome. Thanks in advance.)